# Passing JWT tokens by Ajax/Javascript

Tags: ajax, jwt, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm wondering is it "legitimate" to provide the JWT token I received back from Identity Server to the page so that Javascript can make ajax calls with it as a bearer token to several API endpoints. Clearly these end points would be using SSL, but is this a typical/correct usage pattern?

Cheers,

P

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly doable - if you are OK with the access token being on the client machine/device.

Comment: but is "doable" the same as "recommended". What other way could you make js calls like this?

Comment: "if you are OK with the access token being on the client machine/device." says it all I guess. If that's the case, it is OK.

Comment: are these tokens not always effectively on the device in a .FedAuth cookie for example?